# PlanetData "VelocityAroundSun" giving inconsistent answers

Tags: curated-data, astronomy

My goal is to create a ListPlot showing the Earth's orbital speed over the course of a year, with one datapoint per day.  I'm seeing problems long before I even get to the point of plotting the data!  For example, if I enter: 
    `PlanetData[PlanetData["Earth"], "VelocityAroundSun", "Date" ->DateObject[{2015, 1, 1}]]`

I sometimes get a reasonable response though I don't think it's responding to the "Date" parameter:
    `65546.3mi/h`

and sometimes get:
    `PlanetData[Missing["UnknownEntity", {"Planet", "Earth"}], "VelocityAroundSun"]`
What's the problem?

Comment: Did you really mean `PlanetData["Earth"]` *inside* the brackets, and not `PlanetData["Earth", "VelocityAroundSun", "Date" ->DateObject[{2015, 1, 1}]]` ?